# Solarwinds SDK/customisation

Tags: networking, monitoring

Sorry if this is the wrong place to post, but it is a hybrid serverfault/stackoverflow question.

I've been directed to take a look at **Solarwinds**, which is an excellent network monitoring solution, for an internal project.  Basically we want to write our own panel to display information custom to our network infrastructure.

Has anyone done anything like this, or know if there is a plugin SDK giving developer access?

[edit:] Also, if anyone knows of any other Solarwinds-type open source network solutions, please let me know.

Cheers,

Shane

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you go to [Thwack](http://www.thwack.com), the SolarWinds user community site. You'll find a lot of SolarWinds experts there and their developers participate in the forums.

Answer (score 0):

Solarwinds does use a database behind the scenes - such as Microsoft SQL Server - so you might be able to query the database directly for your purposes... ?